# Fan making noise while running ubuntu

Tags: acpi, fan

Hi i have a newly installed version of ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop. When i run windows, the fan is working properly and is not making sound. but when i run ubuntu, its making sound and is runnning more faster. what could be the problem. Is there any way of rectifying it.

Answer (score 1):

If the fan is working at full speed, then something is wrong with the power saving features of the computer. This problem is hardware-specific, therefore you would need to provide details of the hardware components.

Indeed, one issue would be the graphics card, especially if it is either AMD/ATI or NVidia.
The other issue would be the BIOS of the computer. More often than not, the BIOS does not have correct power saving information that is usable in Linux (while it is usable in Windows). You can google for 'DSDT ubuntu' for more on this.

Therefore, write down the full model number of your computer, and mention which graphics card you have.

Updated: You mention the model number in another reply. I performed the google search and I got several relevant results, such as http://kizwan.blogspot.com/2010/07/acer-aspire-3680-resources-for-mac-os-x.html
The easiest thing to do is update the BIOS to the latest version and try again. If that does not fix the issue, come back again.

Comment: @user2124: could u a bit more precise

Comment: @user2124: how to check which graphics card i am using

Comment: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT
 Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GM
L Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML E
xpress Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio C

Comment: Check my update. You should check if there is any BIOS update available from Acer, which could fix these issues in the most painless way.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

@Chandru1: Based on your model, I found this tutorial that is to enable Frequency Scaling on Celeron:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=582069

That may possibly fix your problem.

If not, try to check your laptop temperature:

http://www.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1200182

which should not be that high (40~60). If it is low, try to slow down the fan manually (following the third link of the bottom) or change manually the frequency of the CPU (second link of the bottom). That may give you a hint.

If it doesn't work, try to install "xserver-xorg-video-intel" video driver as it may be a video related problem, as was suggested by DKuntz2.

---

Maybe these links can help you:

http://embraceubuntu.com/2005/11/04/enabling-cpu-frequency-scaling/

http://maketecheasier.com/how-to-control-your-cpu-frequency-in-ubuntu/2009/04/10

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1333321

Knowing your laptop model could help to provide more specific solutions.

Comment: @lope: Acer aspire 3680

Comment: @Chandru1: please read the Update section of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based off my own experience my fans run in over drive when I don't have proper drivers installed (usually graphics). I would check to see if you have any restricted drivers you could install, and if you do, install them. If you don't, I would check up on your manufacturer's website, find out what kind of graphics card you have and see if you need a driver for it.

I've never had a problem with my CPU causing the fans to go over drive.

Comment: @Dkuntz2: Yes, please check and tell me.

Comment: @Chandru1, check what? I don't know what computer you have, so I can't check it for you. I would be able to give a clearer answer with that information. To check for restricted drivers go to administration -> restricted drivers.

Comment: @Dkuntz2: I have an acer aspire 3680.

Comment: @Dkuntz2: There is no restricted drivers in administration. there is only additional drivers.

Comment: @Chandru1, is it connected to the internet, I've found lots of issues about the wifi not working with Linux, if it's not connected, it might not be getting to the restricted drivers list.

Comment: @Dkuntz2: hey without connecting to the net how can i answer you.

Comment: @Dkuuntz2: As i said there is no restricted drivers list. there is only additional driver list

Comment: @Dkuntz2: And the additional driver is active.

Comment: This package replaces (along with hardware access drivers) the olddriver generation (2.7.x) which consisted of kernel modules only.

It needs a kernel driver to access the hardware. This can be eitherrecent ALSA (shipped with a newer kernel (>=2.6.4) with ALSA supportand snd-intel8x0m module) which is sufficient for basic operation anddata/Internet connection, or the SmartLink kernel driver which isprovided by separate packages which you can build using the source fromthe sl-modem-source package.

This driver

Comment: @Chandru1, you could be using Windows, or another computer. I've seen only one other issue in my polling of the internet, and the suggestion received was either that the computer wasn't in the right power mode (but for the five laptops I've installed ubuntu on that seems unlikely because it does that automatically) or that the computer is broken and needs to go back to acer. That doesn't seem right because you said Windows worked fine. If it's a new computer it might just be that you need to run the battery down all the way and charge it back up to see if the fan stops.

Comment: @Dkuntz2: This is in the additonal drivers option, and i have that driver active.

Comment: @Dkunttz2: It doesn't happen always. During the boot the fan runs abnormally fast and then it starts making sound. Next, if during the boot the fan runs normally, then it doesn't make sound at all. For instance, now its working fine. Its only 2/10 times, the fan makes bad sound.

Comment: When my CR48's fan goes into over drive and the thing is fine, I can just put it to sleep (close the lid) and wake it back up and the fan will no longer be going abnormally fast (though it doesn't go abnormally fast frequently)